# Adobe DTM - is it possible to set custom query string parameters

Tags: adobe-analytics

we're are trying to match the data collection from our pre-DTM tag manager. We had custom data for the Adobe Analytics pev2 query parameter. Specifically, set to the same variable as the eVar and the Prop. I have tried setting s.pev2 in custom page code in the AA section of DTM without success.

```
var trackingString = s.pageName + '|page_nav|' + this.href;
s.linkName = trackingString;
```

Am I headed in the right direction, or is it not possible to customize this parameter?

Comment: Sorry, my code block was incomplete. 
`var trackingString = s.pageName + '|page_nav|' + this.href;
s.linkName = trackingString;`

I was informed s.linkName is the SiteCatalyst variable that determines the value of pev2. Trying to set either s.linkName or s.pev2 in custom code does not change the query string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are headed in the right direction, but the approach is off.

You should create a Data Element within DTM to create the value that you want to place into the variable.  Then use that Data Element to populate that var.

Answer (score 0):

By chance, I discovered that selecting Custom Link in the Link Tracking portion of the Adobe Analytics section. Then setting the Link Name field to my trackingString variable sets the value of pev2.